# My non-nullable ArrayList is returning a null upon calling it and throwing a Null Pointer Exception

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, nullpointerexception

Running this on IntelliJ IDEA 2020.11 using JDK 14 and coding it in Kotlin.

I have a class with a variable menuComponents which is an ArrayList full of MenuComponents, but it's empty at initialization.

```
var menuComponents: ArrayList<MenuComponent> = ArrayList()
```

I want to edit the components so I wrote this.

```
for (component in menuComponents) {
    //Do some stuff. The stuff doesn't matter, it throws an exception if I leave it blank
}
```

When I call on this method, I get a null pointer exception. Additionally, the for loop doesn't even matter.

```
class NPE() {

    init {
        refreshProperties()
    }

    var menuComponents: ArrayList<Double> = ArrayList()

    fun refreshProperties() {
        refreshJMenuComponents()
    }

    private fun refreshJMenuComponents() {
        val i = menuComponents.size
        println("$i is the length.")
        for (index in 0 until menuComponents.size) {
            val component = menuComponents[index]
            println("Refreshed component: $component")
        }
    }
}

fun main() {

    NPE()
}
```

This statement errors out too. I don't change menuComponents at all before I call these, so it should just be equal to a blank array list. I don't know why it's throwing a Null Pointer Exception.

```
menuComponents = arrayListOf(//component 1, component 2)
```

If I try running any of the previous statements on menuComponents now, it still throws a Null Pointer Exception. The value is not nullable, and I am explicitly setting it equal to something, so why is it erroring out at all? It should just not even compile if there is a null object somewhere? It compiles and then throws an exception.

Is this some sort of possible bug or am I just missing something?

Comment: provide a minimal, reproducible example

Comment: The code you've posted will not throw NPE, so something's missing.

Comment: Yeah, so it turns out I just created the variable after I ran the init block, so it hadn't been created yet. Yikes.

Comment: @sidgate Why did you edit all of my stuff? You removed the context to my question and essentially replaced the whole thing. Yes technically the fix to my code was not even related to the question but that doesn't mean you rewrite the whole question to match the fix. I had already answered it and you just changed the question and then changed my answer to answer the new question that I didn't ask. Go upload your own question instead. The new question is also missing information and contradicts itself, and I didn't even ask it.

Comment: Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question did not have enough information, and didn't have any minimal code to reproduce. You instead added that information in self-answer. Anyone visiting this question needs to understand the full context of the problem. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to move the variable initialization above the init block.

```
class NPE() {

    var menuComponents: ArrayList<Double> = ArrayList()

    init {
        refreshProperties()
    }

    fun refreshProperties() {
        refreshJMenuComponents()
    }

    private fun refreshJMenuComponents() {
        val i = menuComponents.size
        println("$i is the length.")
        for (index in 0 until menuComponents.size) {
            val component = menuComponents[index]
            println("Refreshed component: $component")
        }
    }
}

fun main() {

    NPE()
}
```